# Indent Guideline in Text Editor

Tags: python, scripting, interface, customization

Does the text editor have a feature that shows the indentation of the code? If it does, that would be nice to know.

[image: image found in the internet]

Comment: No, it does not. If you want to get into python development in Blender I can highly recommend the Blender Development extension for Visual Studio. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesLucke.blender-development

Comment: That's nice info. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An addon is doing that.

[image]

[You can find it here](https://github.com/K-410/blender-scripts/blob/master/2.8/code_editor.py). It seems to work well in 4.0.

Comment: That's pretty ace

Comment: It works great, Thanks.